# How Swift Array Bounds Checks Optimization works

Tags: arrays, swift, bounds

I was watching [WWDC 2015 session 409 - Optimizing Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/409/) . It mentioned that Swift ensures array access happen in bounds. And Swift can lift checks out of loops. So that O(n) checks become O(1).

The example from the talk looks like this:

```
//Before Optimization
for i in 0..<n {
    precondition (i < length)
    A[i] ^= 13
}

//After Optimization
precondition (i < length)
for i in 0..<n {
    A[i] ^= 13
}
```

From my understanding, the compiler should perform so-called Array Bounds Check when codes get compiled. But I didn't see the compiler's warning when I tested using following codes. Instead it crashed at runtime.

```
 var a = Array(1...5)

 for i in 0..<6 {
     a[i] ^= 13
 }
```

And I did set **Disable Safety Checks** to **No** under **Build Settings**. I think this should turn on the Array Bounds Checks. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Please make _WWDC 2015 session 409_ a link to what it is about (and preferably also use inline code with back-ticks)

Comment: By checking the length inside the loop you would be performing the check multiple times and it would iterate all the array elements anyway. if you move the precondition before the loop it won't even start the iteration if the precondition it is not met

Comment: Why would you expect a warning? The count of the array still isn't known until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from the talk shows the use of precondition(), but your code doesn’t seem to use precondition()

Comment: I think what the OP meant was that the precondition should be inserted by the compiler.

Comment: It clearly isn’t, though I can see why someone might think that from how it was presented in the video.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought the compiler would do the check.